# How to update a value from an enum class

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, enums

I am have a class that I use as a model for my iosApp, this is as below:

```
import Foundation

enum ShopItemSelection: Hashable {
    case ralph
    case target

    var items: [ShopItem] {
        switch self {
        case .ralph:
            return [.meat, .clothes, .fruit]
        case .target:
            return [.meat, .clothes, .fruit, .veggies]
        }
    }
}
```

But in some cases, I need to remove `.clothes` but I do not want to create a ton of case, the case provide default value and in some specific cases, I need to remote an item.

```
var sections: [ShopItemSelection] = []
        
        switch store.size {
        case "SMALL":
            sections.append(.ralph)
        default:
            sections.append(.target)
        }
        
        
        if(store.stillHaveClothes == false) {
            var updatedItems = sections[0].items.filter {
                switch $0 {
                case .clothes: return false
                default: return true
                }
            }
            sections.first?.items = updatedItems
        }
        return sections
```

I tried to update items with the filtered element but Xcode complains that `items is a get-only property`

I need to update items with the filtered elements

How to fix the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't use an `enum` for this problem in this way. You could use a `struct` with a `let storeType: Shop` property where `Shop` is your `enum` with `ralph` and `target` cases. Read [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/enumerations/)

Comment: You could use associated values with your enum cases, but don't. It isn't the right way to approach your problem.